# How to do laplace transform on time dependent domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

I want to solve
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial W(v,z)}{\partial v}&=\frac{\partial^{2} W(v,z)}{\partial z^{2}}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
W(0,z)&=\delta_{a}(z),\quad W(v,\theta(v))=0,\quad \theta(v)\leq z<\infty,\quad 0\leq v<\infty\\
\end{split}
\end{align}

My aim is to solve the problem. I would like to have any standard reference talking about solving the above equation.

Currently, I use Laplace transform, which gives solving (partly)

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
s\hat{W}(s,z)-\delta_{a}(z)&=\frac{\partial^{2} \hat{W}(s,z)}{\partial z^{2}}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}

Clearly, the above equation can be solved. Let's omit detailed derivation for the solution of $\hat{W}(s,x)$. I have tried to work out the solution for $\hat{W}(s,x)$, let say it is $Ae^{\sqrt{s}x}+Be^{-\sqrt{s}x}-\frac{1}{2s}e^{-|x-a|}$. I want to change it back by inverse Laplace transform and find corresponding $A$ and $B$ by matching the boundary condition. However, $A$ and $B$ should be constant, doing in this way may not be suitable.

I think we need to make use boundary values after integral transform. My question is: how to tackle the boundary value problem using Laplace transform?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your result (I didn't check it, the last term seems doubtful) :
$$\hat{W}(s,z)=\hat A(s)e^{\sqrt{s}z}+\hat B(s)e^{-\sqrt{s}z}-\frac{1}{2s}e^{-|z-a|}.$$
Of course, no $x$ must appear in this equation.

The inverse Laplace transform (noted $L^{-1}$) involves convolution (noted $\star$) :
$$W(x,z)=L^{-1}\left(\hat A(s)\right) \star  L^{-1}\left(e^{\sqrt{s}z}\right) +L^{-1}\left(\hat B(s)\right) \star  L^{-1}\left(e^{-\sqrt{s}z}\right)+ \frac12e^{-|z-a|} L^{-1}\left(\frac1s \right)$$

$$W(x,z)=A(x)\star  L^{-1}\left(e^{\sqrt{s}z}\right) +B(x)\star  L^{-1}\left(e^{-\sqrt{s}z}\right)+ \frac12e^{-|z-a|} L^{-1}\left(\frac1s \right)$$

$L^{-1}\left(\frac1s \right)=1$

$L^{-1}\left(e^{\sqrt{s}z}\right)=-\frac{z}{2\sqrt{\pi}x^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{4x} \right)$

$L^{-1}\left(e^{-\sqrt{s}z}\right)=\frac{z}{2\sqrt{\pi}x^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{4x} \right)$

$$W(x,z)=A(x)\star \left( -\frac{z}{2\sqrt{\pi}x^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{4x} \right)\right) +B(x)\star  \left( \frac{z}{2\sqrt{\pi}x^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{4x} \right)\right)+\frac12e^{-|z-a|} $$

$$W(x,z)=C(x)\star \left( \frac{z}{2\sqrt{\pi}x^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{4x} \right)\right) +\frac12e^{-|z-a|} $$

One must not confuse the operator $\star$ with multiplication. Better, use the integral form : Eq.(1) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html

The arbitrary function $C(x)$ has to be determined according to the boundary conditions. This is the main difficulty. Generally this leads to an integral equation which cannot always be analytically solved. All depends on the form of boundary condition. In the present case, I am afraid that is is not possible to go further without specific equation for the boundary condition $W(v,\theta(v))=0$.

Comment: So do you mean that we need to specify $C(x)$ in order to get final result?

I understand your solutions. If I substitute $z=\theta(v)$ into the equation, how can one obtain the $C(x)$? Is it a problem of solving specific integral equation which may have solution?

I know that it may not be possible, but I also want to know that how to determine $C(x)$, i.e. what equation should $C(x)$ satisfy so that we can determine it. Numerical method to determine $C(x)$ is also fine.

Comment: That is not exactly what I said. : One have to know explicitly the boundary condition equation to look if the next equation is solvable for $C(x)$.  $$W(x,\theta(x) )=0=C(x)\star \left( \frac{\theta(x)}{2\sqrt{\pi}x^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\theta(x)^2}{4x} \right)\right) +\frac12e^{-|\theta(x)-a|} $$. These kind of equation involving a convolution integral leads to an integral equation. If $\theta(x)$ is any function, how can we expect saying if the integral equation is analytically solvable or not ? Generally it's not, but sometimes it can be yes.

Comment: About numerical method : Trying to solve numerically the equation for $C(x)$ suppose that $\theta(x)$ is explicitly known. It's a complicated way. Better solve directly the PDE with usual numerical method, starting from the given boundary conditions.

Comment: I understand your point. When I want to know is that if there exists an algorithm to obtain $C(x)$. The equation I have should be sth look like $-\frac{1}{2}e^{-|\theta(v)-a|}=\int_{0}^{u} C(v) \frac{\theta(u)}{2\sqrt{\pi}(u-v)^{\frac{3}{2}}}e^{-\frac{\theta(u)^{2}}{4(u-v)}} dv$ It looks like an integral equation. Should we have a numerical way to obtain $C(x)$?

Of course, even if I have the algorithm, I also need to check regularity conditions, otherwise no use. But I would like to know if such algorithm exists.

Comment: That is a too broad question about solving the integral equations, far from the initial wording of the question. I suggest to edit a new question on the forum, but I am afraid that you could be asked to be more specific. Again, I think that the best way is to use an available algorithm to directly solve the PDE and forget the integral equation.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a different approach :
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial W(v,z)}{\partial v}&=\frac{\partial^{2} W(v,z)}{\partial z^{2}}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
First, look for particular solutions on the form $W_p(v,z)=V(v)Z(z)$
$$\frac{V'}{V}=\frac{Z''}{Z}=\mu^2\quad ;\quad V(v)=e^{\mu^2v}\quad\;\quad Z(z)=e^{\mu z}$$
$\mu$ real or complex constant. And with $C$ any real or complex constant :
$$W_p(v,z)=C e^{\mu^2v+\mu z}$$
The general solution of the PDE is any linear combination of the particular solutions :
$$W(v,z)=\int f(\mu)e^{\mu^2v+\mu z}d\mu$$
$f(\mu)$ is an arbitrary function to be determined  according to the boundary conditions.

The bounds of the integral are also arbitrary, to be determined  according to the boundary conditions.

$W(0,z)=\delta_{a}(z)=\int f(\mu)e^{\mu z}d\mu$

$W(v,\theta(v))=0=\int f(\mu)e^{\mu^2v+\mu \theta(v)}d\mu$

The bounds of the integrals have to be chosen to make the whole consistent.

As guessed, it ends with integral equation. I hope that you will be more lucky with them than with whose from my preceding answer.

Comment: What should I do to continue? I only have one $f(\mu)$ for two different equation. To be frank, I prefer the first equation, but I am not sure if we can have the Volterra equation of first kind.